# failed to generate newParagraphStyle crash

Tags: ios, iphone, nsattributedstring

I have various crashes showing up in my reports that are reporting the following reason:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'failed to generate newParagraphStyle'
```

The app that this is happening on does set a lot of attributed text programmatically (fonts, colors, sometimes paragraph styles), but I can not find any pattern directly related to this. What I do see is almost all of the reports include a reference in the stack trace to some form of setLineBreakMode:

```
-[_UICascadingTextStorage(Accessors) setLineBreakMode:]
```

I have never been able to recreate this myself, but it does show up at a fairly regular basis on my crash reporting. I am not specifically setting the line break mode in any of these places. Any ideas?

EDIT:
I spent more time looking into this and was able to find a pattern to reproduce. So I have a UITextField, and when you hit return on the keyboard the "/n" character is detected and the textfield resigns its first responder status. If at any point after that, you try to modify the text (or attributed text) of the field, it crashes. There is one key element, it only happens if you have typingAttributes set. It does not matter what they are set to.

I tried everything, setting typingAttributes to nil before setting the text, setting a fixed string to make sure it was not what we were setting it to - no luck. Keeps crashing. It seems once you get in this state, the textfield is just broken. A hack to avoid it is to blow away the textfield and create a new one - but its just that. A hack.

Some more interesting info, the way that the code detects the return key was not well written - it detected the "/n" and returned NO in:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

It did not use the appropriate method:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
```

In one place in the app this actually fixed the crash, in other places it was always using the correct method and the crash is still happening. The only work around is to blow away the textfield and create a new one. To me, this seems like a bug in iOS itself.

Comment: i too got crash...clean the project and again rebuild..fixed..dont know whats the problem

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue just now and was able to fix it by setting the `typingAttributes` of the problematic `textField` to `nil` directly before `resignFirstResponder` is called by that same `textField`.

Answer (score 1):

Frankie's solution helped, but still found edge cases that triggered this error:

```
** Assertion failure in -[_UICascadingTextStorage setLineBreakMode:],
/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3512.30.14/TextSystem/_UICascadingTextStorage.m:292
```

My solution was to subclass UITextField and add a hackTextAttributes property:

```
import UIKit

class HackTF: UITextField {
  var hackTextAttributes: [String: AnyObject]

  init(frame: CGRect, textAttributes: [String: AnyObject]) {
    hackTextAttributes = textAttributes
    super.init(frame: frame)
    delegate = self
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }

  func hackSetText(text: String) {
    attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: text, attributes: hackTextAttributes)
  }

  func hackSetAttributedText(text: String, attributes: [String: AnyObject]) {
    hackTextAttributes = attributes
    hackSetText(text)
  }
}

extension HackTF: UITextFieldDelegate {
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    typingAttributes = hackTextAttributes // Make sure fields with no text have appropriate typingAttributes
  }
}

// MARK: Apple Crash Prevention Hack
extension HackTF {
  override func resignFirstResponder() -> Bool {
    var isResigningHack = false
    if self.text?.length == 0 { // if no text, add some text so we won't crash...
      isResigningHack = true
      attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: " ", attributes: hackTextAttributes)
    }

    typingAttributes = nil
    let resign = super.resignFirstResponder()

    if isResigningHack { // clear the text
      attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "", attributes: hackTextAttributes)
    }

    return resign
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help someone. I was able to fix the crash in my case with a simple text field subclass, inspired by [mcm's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35634771/2440562).

```
class VLAttributedTextField: UITextField {
    override func resignFirstResponder() -> Bool {
        self.typingAttributes = self.defaultTextAttributes
        let resign = super.resignFirstResponder()

        return resign
    }
}
```

As mentioned above, setting typingAttributes to nil (or empty dictionary) doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the typingAttributes on the textfield is just half of the story.
If you have a delegate set on the UITextField, nullify that too.
I needed both to make this crash go away.